# IUpdateHandler causing NullPointerException

Tags: android, andengine

I'm using GLES2, my code is based on a tutorial I've found online at jimmaru's blog,
inside the GameScene class:

```
IUpdateHandler detect ;
```

And Here's the update handler causing the issue, and this code is inside the createScene() method.

```
detect = new IUpdateHandler() {

        @Override
        public void reset() {
        }

        @Override
        public void onUpdate(float pSecondsElapsed) {

         // Do Stuff 
    };

registerUpdateHandler(detect);
```

And Here's the LogCat output after loading the gamescene.

```
04-27 13:33:46.218      715-731/com.wordpress.jimmaru.android.jimvaderstutorial E/AndroidRuntime﹕ FATAL EXCEPTION: UpdateThread
java.lang.NullPointerException
        at org.andengine.engine.handler.UpdateHandlerList.onUpdate(UpdateHandlerList.java:47)
        at org.andengine.entity.Entity.onManagedUpdate(Entity.java:1395)
        at org.andengine.entity.scene.Scene.onManagedUpdate(Scene.java:282)
        at org.andengine.entity.Entity.onUpdate(Entity.java:1167)
        at org.andengine.engine.Engine.onUpdateScene(Engine.java:590)
        at org.andengine.engine.Engine.onUpdate(Engine.java:585)
        at org.andengine.engine.LimitedFPSEngine.onUpdate(LimitedFPSEngine.java:56)
        at org.andengine.engine.Engine.onTickUpdate(Engine.java:547)
        at org.andengine.engine.Engine$UpdateThread.run(Engine.java:819)
```

What could be the issue?

Answer (score 0):

if you put the IUpdateHandler into the createScene(), you need make a reference for the method, something like this

```
    this.mEngine.registerUpdateHandler(new FPSLogger());
    this.mEngine.registerUpdateHandler(new IUpdateHandler() {
        public void onUpdate(float pSecondsElapsed) {
            MyMethod();
        }

        public void reset() {
        }
    });
```

But is more easy if you put the code before the methods, and after the vars, like this::

```
...
private int Xvar;


IUpdateHandler detect = new IUpdateHandler() {
    @Override
    public void reset() {
    }

    @Override
    public void onUpdate(float pSecondsElapsed) {
        //Do Stuff
    }
};

@Override
public EngineOptions onCreateEngineOptions() {
....
```

I think that the problem is that the method OnUpdate is only executing 1 time in your code, i hope that that work for you!